# Reaction of 2,4,6-triaminobenzoic acid in a protic medium and heat

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

The given answer is (A). At first I thought that it was a simple decarboxylation (due to high heat).

But that does not seem feasible at all as the ring has no electron withdrawing groups which stabilise the carbanion; infact it has electron donating groups which rules out decarboxylation. What else could be a possible mechanism here?

Edit:In the answer posted below could anyone explain how the hydrolysis of triamminobenzene occurs?

Comment: Redraw the starting material as its imino tautomer and maybe it will become clearer

Comment: It is normal decarboxylation - pericyclic. Carbanion isn't usual intermediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial guess for the product was Phloroglucinol, or 1,3,5-trihydroxybenzene<sup>1,2</sup>

> [image]

Belskaya et al.<sup>3</sup> says that 1,3,5-triaminobenzene can be formed, but it can eventually be hydrolyzed to Phloroglucinol

> [image]
> [image]

The sources mention decarboxylation as the mechanism. Note that it is the trihydroxylamine **10** that is getting decarboxylated here. The mechanism becomes clearer if you consider the imino tautomers **6** or **7** with the acid group attached and then dehydrate.

In short, Phloroglucinol should be the final product. If that is not one of the options, then 1,3,5-triaminobenzene is the answer you should select.

**References:**

1. “PHLOROGLUCINOL.” Organic Syntheses, vol. 9, **1929**, *p. 74*. doi:[10.15227/orgsyn.009.0074](https://doi.org/10.15227/orgsyn.009.0074)
2. Tewari, K.S and Vishnoi, N.K : [A textbook of organic chemistry, 4th edition](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=G0l1DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA554&ots=3eplVjhqya&dq=2%2C4%2C6-triaminobenzoic%20acid%20decarboxylation&pg=PA555#v=onepage&q=2,4,6-triaminobenzoic%20acid%20decarboxylation&f=false).
3. Olga B.Belskaya, Valentin P.Talsi, Roman M.Mironenko, Vladimir A.Rodionov, Sergey V.Sysolyatin, Vladimir A.Likholobov, "Transformation pathways of 2,4,6-trinitrobenzoic acid in the aqueous-phase hydrogenation over Pd/C catalyst", Journal of Molecular Catalysis. doi: [10.1016/j.molcata.2016.04.014](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcata.2016.04.014)

Comment: Did you notice it's "side reactions" there? It's not usual at all. Also catalytic hydrogenation environment can influence things.